# else statement does work in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to work out Babbage's difference machine in C. I wrote all the basic idea of the concept: If you are about to find square of 10, for example, first you have to find square of integers before 10. This is how Babbage's machine works.
So in my program we have a list of integers and we assume that we already squares of these integers. Giving this information, it must be capable of working out square of any positive integer, without making any multiplication.

BUT, the code just does not execute the "else" part in if-else statements. However, when I deleted everything in "else" statement and simply wrote a printf function, it supplied the conditions well.

So something must be wrong in the else statement, am I doing appending items to array wrong? Is it not allowed to write for loops in If-Else statement in C? I wrote the same algorithm in python and it works well!

ps: I already tried to write a do-while instead of "else" part.

please help, thanks in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int integers[] = {0,1,2};
int sq_of_integers[] = {0,1,4};
int first_differences[] = {1,3};
int second_difference[] = {2};
int input;
int i;
int x;
int end2 = 2;
int end1 = 1;

for ( i = 0 ; i<=2 ; i++){
    printf("Enter a number to be squared: ");
    scanf(" %d", &input);

    if (input <= integers[end2]){
        printf("It is already known, sir.\n");
    }else{
        for( x = 0 ; x<= input - integers[-1] ; x++){

            // Calculation of the square root:
            integers[end2+1] = integers[end2]+1;
            sq_of_integers[end2+1] = second_difference[0] + first_differences[end1] + sq_of_integers[end2];
            first_differences[end1+1] = sq_of_integers[end2] +sq_of_integers[-2];
            printf(sq_of_integers[end2]);
            end2 = end2 + 1;
            end1 = end1 + 1;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ``integers[-1]`` ?????

Comment: Indexes start at zero so `-1` is invalid

Comment: I guess we have a Python guy here..

Comment: yes, c doesn't support indexing an array from the end, only the beggining

Comment: Also, `integers` is a global array of fixed size; you can't append new values to it without invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input - integers[-1]` has undefined value. Probably it was negative and so you exit the `for` loop without processing it once.

Edit: Complete review of code. Please ask if you don't understand something.

You were trying to use `printf()` without a format argument, probably you compile without warnings. Try to use the command I give to compile.

There was also an index error in your calculation of `first_differences` values.

small.c:

```
/*
Compile with MinGW for Windows:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o small.exe small.c

Compile with linux gcc:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o small small.c
*/

#define N_UPPER_LIMIT 1023

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long integers[N_UPPER_LIMIT + 1] = {0, 1, 2};
    long sq_of_integers[N_UPPER_LIMIT + 1] = {0, 1, 4};
    long first_differences[N_UPPER_LIMIT] = {1, 3};
    long second_difference[] = {2};
    int end1 = 1;
    int end2 = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int input;

        printf("Enter a number to be squared: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf(" %d", &input);

        if (input < 0)
        {
            printf("It is negative, sir.\n");
        }
        else if (input <= integers[end2])
        {
            printf("It is already known, sir.\n");
            printf("square(%ld) = %ld\n", integers[input], sq_of_integers[input]);
        }
        else if (input > N_UPPER_LIMIT)
        {
            printf("Please do not go further than %d, sir.\n", N_UPPER_LIMIT);
        }
        else
        {
            while (input > integers[end2])
            {
                // Calculation of the square root:
                integers[end2 + 1] = integers[end2] + 1;
                sq_of_integers[end2 + 1] = second_difference[0]
                    + first_differences[end1] + sq_of_integers[end2];
                first_differences[end1 + 1] = sq_of_integers[end2 + 1]
                    - sq_of_integers[end2];
                end2++;
                end1++;
                printf("square(%ld) = %ld\n", integers[end2], sq_of_integers[end2]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It could be a good exercise to get rid of the static limit. If you want to do so, you will have to allocate memory for your variables with `malloc()`, and either put a limit as a program argument, or try to change the size allocated with calls to aither `malloc()` of `realloc()`.

Comment: I think this is just impossible. Because I tried this: Remove everything in the for loop, put a single printf function with an ordinary string. And it looped the string 3 three times, as expected. So there must be something wrong with the statements in the for loop. 
As mentioned in the comments below my question, the problem seems to be adding items to a list. Any ideas?

Comment: You were still using integers[-1] in your `for` loop? Because modifying your code may change the value of integers[-1].

Comment: Okay, so I typed integer two, instead of integers[-1]. I also replaced every "-1" index with corresponding index. But still no outcome for "else" part of the decision.

Comment: Did you put a `printf("Something\n");` instruction before the `for` loop in the `else` statement?

Comment: okay, good try. I did it and printed well. So we are sure that it enters to "else" part. there is something wrong with the for loop's statement. For example, do you think that adding items to the lists are correct? I m new to C, so am I to the syntax.

Comment: As said ShadowRanger, you use rooted size arrays and try to extend them, this will quickly raise overlapping allocations and also will probably lead to segmentation faults (the most common C error). It's dirty, but you can try to set your array with size 1024 just to check it is better with this.

Comment: not working, I think I should study on lists even more before diving in them. thanks so very much anyway,

Comment: Could you put the last version of your code on paste.bin or any equivalent and send me the link?

Comment: this was an answer with full awesome tips! You just clarified my bunch of questions in my mind. Thanks a lot!